# Twitter bootstrap Menu Dropdown, height issue, on hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, mouseover

Am using Bootstrap for creating navbar and its inner menu automatically drop's down on mouse over with additional CSS. When we shrink the screen size to mobile, and mouse over on item that has a drop down - in my case its "Products", there is an additional scroll bar that shows up besides drop down and few items are getting hidden.

Here is the [code pen link](http://codepen.io/suman_codepen/pen/gMrLgz)

HTML Code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a></div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS Code :

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

I think the issue is with the height of the navbar. How do i get rid of the scroll bar besides drop down and see if the navbar can expand when displaying dropdown menu.

Comment: `navbar` has got `max-height:340px`.. and `.navbar-collapse-in`  has `overflow-y:auto` that makes it scroll.. **[How about this](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/EyKNQg)**?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your rule in a media-query because `hover` won't be used on smaller viewports in the first place.

Working Example

```css
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="navbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Top Navigation -->
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">One</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Four</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Five</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Six</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```